# What on / off switch to use from a 2S Lipo to a Switching Regulator

Tags: batteries, switches, lipo

Last time i used the [Slide Switch](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/OS102011MA1QN1/CKN9559-ND/1981430) for my application, everything worked well. The system has 2S (7.4v Lipo) Battery - Fuse - On/Off Switch - Switching Regulator - load ( Beaglebone + Wifi Module).

Now when i rechecked the website, i realized the switch is rated 12v 100mA. This is the scary part, although nothing got burnt or fried the last time, do i need to change the switch? can i use the same switch?

Is it better to use a rocker switch with a higher current specification and have it connected via a wire?

Comment: Geesh... Its hard to believe the current rating of that switch is really that low! You never mentioned what the load current really is expected to be though, so its hard to say for sure. But a mechanical switch with that low a contact rating would make me want to crunch the actual numbers too! :-)

Comment: The Beaglebone does 200-850mA on peak load, 
WiFI device shouldnt do more than 250mA and there is another modem device which does around 300mA. So A load of around 2A i would say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i ended up using a Cherry Switch. 
http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/PRK22J5DBBNN/CH865-ND/1083858